# Not sure why my tree building function is returning an empty array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm taking a flat array and creating a tree from it using the following function, but it always returns an empty array (`$branch = array()`) on this set of data.

```
 public static function buildTree($activities, $parent = 0)
    {
        $branch = array();

        foreach ($activities as $activity) {
            if ($activity['in_reply_to'] == $parent) {
                $children = self::buildTree($activities, $activity['activity_id']);

                if ($children) {
                    $activity['children'] = $children;
                }

                $branch[] = $activity;
            }
        }

        return $branch;
    }
```

And here's the data set.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [activity_id] => 583069095760826322
            [in_reply_to] => 583068167603269635
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [activity_id] => 583068167603269635
            [in_reply_to] => 582781728499965991
        )

)
```

`in_reply_to` references the `activity_id`.

So, you can see that `0` is actually a child of `1`.

We don't have the data for the parent of `1`, so that should just be ignored based on the function.

Anyway, this is always returning an empty array and I'm not sure why.

Comment: How do you call this function? Do you initially pass parent_id?

Comment: No, it's just called with self::buildTree($activities);

Comment: But then $parent is equal to 0 by default. And your condition will never be satisfied. So, you'll get an empty array.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returns an empty array when I run it with `buildTree($activities, $activites[0]['activity_id'])`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not on the code but on your data, you don't have a root node with  `"in_reply_to" = 0`

Try to execute your code with this data set:

```
$activities = array(
    array("activity_id" => 583069095760826322, "in_reply_to" => 583068167603269635), 
    array("activity_id" => 583068167603269635, "in_reply_to" => 0)
);
```

Comment: That should work, but changing the data set isn't really a viable option. This is all coming from the database and the IDs are set as-is and need to be in the final tree the way they came from the database.

Comment: You're building an activity system or something like comment system. So, there is the first activity, and the replies to this activity. My question is: What is the data for this first activity?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `activity_id`-field is auto incrementing r otherwise ordered, then you can find the lowest id inside your activities-array with this function and use it as the root.

```
public static function findLowestActivityID($activities)
{
    $id = null;
    foreach ($activities as $activity) {
        if ($id === null || $id > $activity['activity_id']) {
            $id = $activity['activity_id'];
        }
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Example-Call:

```
$rootID = YourClassName::findLowestActivityID($activities);
$result = YourClassName::buildTree($activities, $rootID);
```